# How to match any non-newline character in ANTLR 4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am wondering how to match a non-newline character in a grammar where a newline is a terminal in the hopes of using it to match, for instance, the title file that may contain numbers punctuation and so on.

The grammar I am working with right now is:

```
grammar ABCHeaderNew;
import Configuration;

root: header EOF;

header: index title; 
index: 'X:' INDEX stop+;
title: 'T:' TITLE stop+;

INDEX: INTEGER+;
TITLE: ANY+;

stop: comment | NEWLINE; 
comment: '%' ANY* NEWLINE;

INTEGER: [0-9];
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
ANY: ~(NEWLINE);

WHITESPACE: [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

This doesn't compile (error message: rule reference NEWLINE is not currently supported in a set). There are several other variations that I tried that do not work either.

Does anyone know a good workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The not operator only operates on a set, and a token reference, such as `NEWLINE` does not qualify.

Just use a normal set representation

```
ANY  : ~[\r\n] ;
```

Caveat: you may want to expand the definition to exclude escaped line end characters, depending on your ultimate needs of course.